# R locale problems on Ubuntu - e.g. blank page saved using ggsave

Tags: r, locale, dbi

In my simple R script on Ubuntu I just connect to a database and plot a simple plot.
Surprisingly, the plot is saved as a blank page. It is saved correctly if I do not call `dbConnect`.

```
library(ggplot2)
print(Sys.getlocale())
conn<-DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), server=####, uid=####, 
 driver="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/psqlodbcw.so", pwd=####)
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:3, y=3:1), aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
print(Sys.getlocale())
ggsave("plot.pdf")
```

I suspect is is because DBI does something bad with locales. Here is the output:

```
[1] "LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=lt_LT.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=lt_LT.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=lt_LT.UTF-8;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=lt_LT.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"
encoding name too long
[1] "LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=lt_LT.UTF-8;LC_TIME=lt_LT.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=lt_LT.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=lt_LT.UTF-8;LC_NAME=lt_LT.UTF-8;LC_ADDRESS=lt_LT.UTF-8;LC_TELEPHONE=lt_LT.UTF-8;LC_MEASUREMENT=lt_LT.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=lt_LT.UTF-8"
Saving 7 x 7 in image
```

How to make DBI not modify the locale?

Answer (score 1):

Locales is the most frustrating aspect of R for me so far. I was not able to fix it from within R. The only thing that worked is to set the shell variables outside - in my case I just put them in my virtualenv `activate` script.

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
export LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
```